# Type class java.lang.RuntimeException is neither a @NodeEntity nor a @RelationshipEntity

Tags: neo4j, runtimeexception, spring-data-neo4j

I am trying to upgrade the 'spring-data-neo4j' dependency on our project from 2-1-0-M1 version (using neo4j 1.6) to 2.2.0.RELEASE (with neo4j 1.8.1) version. However, when I change the version of spring-data-neo4j dependency, even to 2.1.0.RELEASE, I get the following exception when starting application on Tomcat:

```
[ERROR] [host-startStop-1] [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader:307] - Context initialization failed   
 org.springframework.data.neo4j.mapping.InvalidEntityTypeException: Type class java.lang.RuntimeException is neither a @NodeEntity nor a @RelationshipEntity
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jMappingContext.createPersistentEntity(Neo4jMappingContext.java:56)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jMappingContext.createPersistentEntity(Neo4jMappingContext.java:46)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:269)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(Neo4jMappingContext.java:61)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(Neo4jMappingContext.java:46)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:246)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.initialize(AbstractMappingContext.java:346)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.onApplicationEvent(AbstractMappingContext.java:336)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.onApplicationEvent(AbstractMappingContext.java:69)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:97)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:324)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:929)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:467)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:384)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4887)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5381)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:977)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1655)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I have also tried to only 'upgrade' the 'spring-data-neo4j' library (and let neo4j on v1.6) and got the exception too. Thus the exception seems to be only related to the spring-data-neo4j library and not neo4j itself.

Has anyone seen this behaviour before, or has any clue why Spring-data-neo4j thinks that RuntimeException should be either NodeEntity or RelationshipEntity?

Unfortunatly, the code is distributed among multiple projects, what makes it difficult to paste a minimum configuration here that causes the problem. Still working on that. Already 'cleaned up' all neo4j entity (and relation) classes and DAO's by removing all annotations and content to be sure that it's not related to any of them. Still, when starting the application the exception arises.

Edit: below is the spring configuration used:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"  standalone="no"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:neo4j="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j/spring-neo4j-2.0.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="nl.graph" />
    <tx:annotation-driven mode="proxy"/>

    <bean id="graphDb" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/neo4j/graphDb" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="graphDatabaseService" class="org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase"
        destroy-method="shutdown">
        <constructor-arg index="0" ref="graphDb" />
    </bean>

    <neo4j:config graphDatabaseService="graphDatabaseService" />

    <neo4j:repositories base-package="nl.graph.repositories" />

    <bean id="neo4jTransactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager">
        <property name="transactionManager">
            <bean class="org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.SpringTransactionManager">
                <constructor-arg index="0" ref="graphDatabaseService" />
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="userTransaction">
            <bean class="org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.UserTransactionImpl">
                <constructor-arg index="0" ref="graphDatabaseService" />
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Edit 21-05: Found the cause, in some application context the following bean was defined:

```
<bean id="runtimeException" class="java.lang.Class" factory-method="forName">
    <constructor-arg value="java.lang.RuntimeException"/>
</bean>
```

Removing this bean (which was defined for spring-batch's FaultTolerantStepFactoryBean's skippableExceptionClasses property) solved the problem. Somehow this bean was thus found by neo4j component scan?

Comment: Are you providing an base-package or initial-entity set in your spring config? Could you share your spring configuration for Spring Data Neo4j ?

Comment: Posted the Spring configuration for Spring Data Neo4j. I assume you are pointing to the <context:component-scan part of the configuration? It's using base-package indeed.

Comment: Somehow it thinks that java.lang.RuntimeException should be added as an entity. Do you have some uncommon use of RuntimeException in your entities? E.g. as field or so? Or have a custom exception that inherits from runtime exception in that package?

Comment: Thats the weird part, since there is no Exception in the package nl.graph. I even have cleaned up all classes in this package (and subpackages) and only left the annotation org.springframework.stereotype.Repository no the DaoImpl, and the exception still arises when starting the application. See the code in dao package http://codetidy.com/5645/ and domain http://codetidy.com/5646/

Comment: You have no @NodeEntity annotation on your domain objects? And also no data fields? How do you plan to map them to the graph?

Comment: I did have them, but because I got the exception I cleaned up all of it to see if it was related to the annotations. But apparently not.

Comment: Can you share the correct entities in the package?